# OptaPlanner - Problem with using @PlanningListVariable and @PlanningVariable in the same planning entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, optaplanner

I created a planning entity that represents a lesson and in that entity I defined two planning variables and one planning list variable. Program was working normally before adding a planning list variable and then it resulted

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The config (ValueSelectorConfig(null)) has no configured variableName for entityClass (class com.tmtblback.dto.LessonDto) and because there are multiple variableNames ([room, studentGroups, timeslot]), it cannot be deduced automatically.
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Mixing `@PlanningListVariable` with `@PlanningVariable` is not possible in the current version of OptaPlanner (8.24.1.Final).

The list variable feature is still under development so it's not yet documented and it misses the support for many advanced use cases, including mixing with basic planning variables.

Your use case seems valid and I think it should eventually be supported. I have filed https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2755 to track the requirement.